# The jquery cookie script doesnt work

Tags: jquery, cookies, session-cookies

Hi guys I have this line in the header :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Its Jquery cookie plug-in that should do the job but when I combine it the following script it simple doesnt work. What do I do  wrong?

```
  if( !$.cookie('visited')){


    $(function () {    
    $('#cookiz').hide();
    }); 


    } else {
        $(function () {

    $.cookie('visited', 'yes');     
    $('#cookiz').show();
    $("#aceptar").click(function(){ $("#cookiz").hide(1000); });


    });

    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in your `if` statement is not working.

Try this:

```
$(function () {    
  if( $.cookie('visited')=='yes' ) $('#cookiz').hide();
  else {
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes');     
    $('#cookiz').show();
    $("#aceptar").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $("#cookiz").hide(1000); });
  }
});
```

If this doesn't work, make sure your `cookie.js` script has a valid source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesnt seems to work. U chekc the sours and it is fine. What shoud I check next?

Comment: Check if the cookie is being written in the browser.